# Karma: Error during loading "karma-phantomjs-launcher" plugin

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am trying to run tests on Centos 7 within the Node.js (6.1.0) environment. After I run

```
./node_modules/karma/bin/karma --log-level debug start
```

I get the error message:

```
Error during loading "karma-phantomjs-launcher" plugin:
Path must be a string. Received null
```

In karma.conf.js I have mentioned plugins and the browser:

```
'plugins': ['karma-mocha', 'karma-chai', 'karma-sinon', 'karma-chai-sinon', 'karma-coverage', 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-phantomjs-launcher', 'karma-chrome-launcher', 'karma-babel-preprocessor'],
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
```

I also have installed all plugins locally for the project. All other plugins are loaded without a problem.

I have also the same project running on Windows 7 environment without a problem.

Answer (score 10):

Removing the `node_modules` directory and re-installing `npm` packages again helped me:

```
rm -r node_modules/
```

or with `rimraf`:

```
rimraf node_modules/
```

and re-adding all dependencies:

```
npm i
```

Comment: how to run rimraf node_modules/
  on the shell? XD

Comment: You have to install `rimraf`before, of course. Like: `npm install -g rimraf`

Answer (score 1):

Since we weren't using `phantomjs` for testing, I was able to resolve the issue by removing `"karma-phantomjs-launcher"` from the `karma.conf.js`

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is related to the fact that I tried to use `phantomjs-prebuilt`. Here is what I did, installed `phantomjs` and added the following to `karma.conf.js`

```
process.env.PHANTOMJS_BIN = './node_modules/.bin/phantomjs'
```

Because it was complaining about missing PhantomJs otherwise:

```
[launcher]: No binary for PhantomJS browser on your platform.
  Please, set "PHANTOMJS_BIN" env variable.
```